# Angularjs kendo treeview not showing checboxes in Kendo popup

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, treeview, kendo-treeview

I am using Kendo Window in which I am showing Kendo TreeView with checboxes. The issue is that treeview renders correctly but checkboxes does not show. If I render treeview outside Kendo Window (i.e., directly in my page) then it showing checboxes correctly.

Please help as I am stuck. Below is the code that I use:

```
<div kendo-tree-view k-options="treeOptions" k-data-source="treeDataSource"></div>


$scope.treeOptions = {
   checkboxes: {
      checkChildren: true
   }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code seems to work fine:

```
<div kendo-window>
  <div kendo-tree-view k-options="treeOptions" k-data-source="treeDataSource"></div>
</div>
<script>
  angular.module("app", ["kendo.directives"]).controller("controller", function($scope) {
    $scope.treeOptions = {
      checkboxes: {
        checkChildren: true
      }
    };
    $scope.treeDataSource =  [
        { text: "Furniture", expanded: true, items: [
            { text: "Tables & Chairs" },
            { text: "Sofas" },
            { text: "Occasional Furniture" }
        ] },
        { text: "Decor", items: [
            { text: "Bed Linen" },
            { text: "Curtains & Blinds" },
            { text: "Carpets" }
        ] }
    ];
  });
</script>
```

Live demo: http://dojo.telerik.com/@korchev/INezO/2

Comment: Thanks Atanas for your reply. Actually I treeOptions code into the click event of a button, that is why it was not working. According to you, we should specify treeOptions directly inside controller.